# Burn: How to store a checkbox value in a variable

Tags: checkbox, wix, wix3.6, burn

I was wondering how you store a checkbox value in a variable? 
I am using WiX **Burn** with a custom RtfTheme.

For example:

*RtfTheme.xml*

```
<Checkbox Name="TestCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-51" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">Please select this box</Checkbox>
```

*Bundle.wxs*

```
<Variable Name="TestVariable" Type="numeric" Value="![CDATA[TestCheckbox]]"/>
```

I want the value of "TestVariable" to change value whenever I select or deselect the checkbox. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WixStdBA automatically saves the state of all named checkbox controls that appear on the Options page. WixStdBA doesn't expose any other checkbox values.

Comment: Do you mean that if we want to define an additional checkbox, its value will be hidden?

To better clarify my question we want to pass the checkbox value to an msi that is part of the bundle. (We have to store the value of the new checkbox in variable which we can pass as command line parameter to a package inside the bindle/chain)

Comment: No, I mean that other checkboxes are ignored entirely. WixStdBA only sets variable values for checkboxes on the Options page.

Comment: Hi Bob, This time I am using Wixtool V3.10, since checkbox's values are not reflecting in variables in Bootstrap application. This issue has been raised after updated to V3.10