# How to use the check box value in wix bootstrapper?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Add one checkbox in the HyperlinkTheme.xml like

```
<Checkbox Name="MyCheckBox" X="18" Y="191" Width="-11" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">Install Driver</Checkbox>
```

How can i use this in bootstrapper? I have modified the Bundle.wxs file like,

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="..\..\..\..\install\MyMSI.msi" InstallCondition="MyCheckBox" ForcePerMachine="yes" Vital="yes" Visible="yes" />
```

But this doesn't work properly. It didn't install the MyMSI.msi but the check box value is "selected". did I miss anything. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me as soon as possible. Little bit urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Is your checkbox in the Options page in `HyperlinkTheme.xml`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640470/burn-how-to-store-a-checkbox-value-in-a-variable?rq=1) from WiX developer Bob Arnson, all checkboxes except for the ones added to the Options page are simply ignored.

*HyperlinkTheme.xml*:

```
<Page Name="Options">
    <Text X="11" Y="80" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsHeader)</Text>
    <Text X="11" Y="121" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.OptionsLocationLabel)</Text>
    <Editbox Name="FolderEditbox" X="11" Y="143" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" />
    <Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="142" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">#(loc.OptionsBrowseButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsOkButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="OptionsCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsCancelButton)</Button>

    <!-- Additional checkbox control -->
    <Checkbox Name="MyCheckBox" X="-11" Y="-173" Width="260" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">#(loc.MyCheckbox)</Checkbox>
</Page>
```

If you did add it to the Options page, there might be a problem with the way to used the condition in the `bundle.wxs` file. Try the method used in the question linked above and see how that works:

```
<Variable Name="MyVariable" Type="numeric" Value="![CDATA[MyCheckBox]]"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `<MsiPackage` element, state `InstallCondition="MyCheckBox=1"`